# How to programmatically add content to a group in the Group Module?

Tags: nodes, 8, group

I'm using the [Group](https://www.drupal.org/project/group) module. If I have a group type such as Project, and I have a content type such as Article, and I programmatically created a new article node using Node::create(), how can I in the same code add this article as content to a project that I choose?

Answer (score 1):

If the problem is just to add an article to a group, the group module directly offers the following function for this. See `GroupInterface.php`

```
public function addContent(ContentEntityInterface $entity, $plugin_id, $values = []);
```

In an example `$group->addContent($node, $pluginId);`

Answer (score 0):

Given you have the group entity and node entity, you can simply create a GroupContent entity.

```
$groupEntity = ... The group entity.
$node = ... The node entity.

$type = $type = $groupEntity->getGroupType()->id() . '-group_node-' . $node->getType();

$groupContentEntity = \Drupal\group\Entity\GroupContent::create([
    'gid' => $groupEntity->id(),
    'entity_id' => $node->id(),
    'type' => $type,
]);
$groupContentEntity->save();
```

Comment: Could you clarify, is it necessary to create a plugin to get permission for it like here (https://www.drupal.org/node/2723911) ?
Or I can have a node entity, a group entity and simply add the node to the group without writing the plugin ? And in this case will all users of the group be able to edit content of the node ?

Answer (score 0):

Once installed the type of relationship in the group with the code feels should be sufficient for Drupal 8, 9, 10.

```
$node = Node::create([
  'type' => 'node_type',
  'title' => 'My title',
  'uid' => $uid,
]);
$node->save();

$group->addRelationship($node, 'group_node:company_access_request');
```